# Initializing struct array inside superclass constructor

Tags: c++

I would like to call the superclass constructor and directly give it an array of "MyStruct" structs. I have tried to demonstrate this below. In the main method I'm creating an instance of "Foo" with the structs, but this doesn't work in the superclass constructor inside of the "Bar" class. How can this be achieved correctly?

```
struct MyStruct
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

class Foo
{
private:
    MyStruct* m_MyStructArray;
    int m_MyStructLength;
public:
    Foo(MyStruct* myStructArray, int myStructLength)
        : m_MyStructArray(myStructArray), m_MyStructLength(myStructLength) {}
    ~Foo() {}
    const MyStruct* getMyStructArray() { return m_MyStructArray; }
    int getCount() { return m_MyStructLength; }
};

class Bar : Foo
{
public:
    Bar()
        : Foo((MyStruct*) { {10, 10}, { 10, 10 } }, 2) {} //This doesn't work obviously
    ~Bar() {}
};


int main() {
    MyStruct myStructs[] = {
            { 10, 10 },
            { 20, 20 },
    };
    Foo foo(myStructs, 2);
}
```

Comment: You'd probably have to create a static array and forward a pointer to it to `Foo`.

Comment: Consider that `m_MyStructArray` is a pointer, not an array.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x Hmm... Yes, thought about that as well, but it isn't very elegant though. If there isn't another solution I'll do it that way.

Comment: `Foo` takes `MyStruct*` and  `int` arguments. In Bar you are not giving these 2 information to the constructor

Comment: Don't go for static arrays like that. Use `vector` or `std::array` and your probelm will go away.

Comment: @SergeyA The problem is that the data needs to be tightly packed in memory, so vector wouldn't be an option in this case. std::array wouldn't work either, because it has to be a variable size. Any other ideas?

Comment: @DamyvanValenberg, what do you mean by 'tightly packed in memory'?

Comment: @SergeyA Sorry, I got confused with a std::list. With tightly packed I meant it has to be in sequence in memory without gaps. So, your solution does work, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As is usually the case, the problem lies within usage of outdated language constructs. Here is how one should do it:

```
#include <vector>
struct MyStruct
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

class Foo
{
private:
    std::vector<MyStruct> m_MyStructArray;
public:

    Foo(const std::vector<MyStruct> myStructArray)
        : m_MyStructArray(std::move(myStructArray)) {}
    ~Foo() = default;
    const auto& getMyStructArray() const { return m_MyStructArray; }
    auto getCount() const { m_MyStructArray.size(); }
};

class Bar : Foo
{
public:
    Bar()
        : Foo({ {10, 10}, { 10, 10 } }) {} //This does work
    ~Bar() = default;
};


int main() {
    Foo foo({{ 10, 10}, {20, 20 }});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest moving away from your path. Storing a pointer to an array that was passed from a calling function has lots of pitfalls. Start using `std::vector` (if the size is dynamic) or `std::array` (if size is static) instead.

```
class Foo
{
  private:
    std::vector<MyStruct> m_MyStructArray;
    // No need for the additional member variable to
    // store the size of the array. std::vector already
    // does that.

  public:

    Foo(std::vector<MyStruct> const& myStructArray) : m_MyStructArray(myStructArray){}

    ...

};
```

Then, the constructor of `Bar` can use a syntax of the form that you were hoping to use for an array.

```
class Bar : Foo
{
  public:
    Bar() : Foo({ {10, 10}, {10, 10} }) {}
    ~Bar() {}
};
```

**Having said that, if you must store a pointer ...**

You can use a member funcion of `Bar` to return a pointer to an array that can be passed to the base class constructor.

```
class Bar : Foo
{
  public:
    Bar() : Foo(getMyStructArray(), 2) {}
    ~Bar() {}

 private:

   static MyStruct* getMyStructArray()
   {
     static MyStruct myStructs[] = { { 10, 10 }, { 10, 10 }};
     return myStructs;
   } 
};
```

Comment: I feel like it is in great part a copy of my answer?

Comment: @SergeyA, You are right. In this particular case, we thought alike.